# Calculate the maximum value across all rows without manually typing the names of every column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying create a new column with the maximum value of each row using dplyr. So far I have this:

```
dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(max=max())
```

The data.frame "dat" has 976 columns. How can I run max() without manually typing the names of every column.

Thank you

Comment: You can do `dat %>% mutate(rowmax = do.call(pmax, .))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get some data:

```r
m <- tibble(matrix(runif(1000 * 500), ncol = 500))
```

Make sure every column is a double, then this should ideally work:

```r
m_with_max_col <- m %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max = max(c_across(where(is.numeric))))
```

This also works, but might be less desirable:

```r
m_with_max_col <- m %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max = max(across()))
```

Solution is taken from : [Row-wise operations](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html)